# move_base footprint

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-hydro, footprint, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a problem with the move_base package. It keeps saying those kind of things :

```
[ WARN] [1402905398.913790779]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 3.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.5543 seconds
```

And after the first time an error is prited. Meaning I run it once, it gets a lots of warning and the robot just go crazy and then I have this error the second time, along with the above warning :

```
[ERROR] [1402905389.655349880]: You must specify at least three points for the robot footprint, reverting to previous footprint.
```

The thing is I'm not using the footprint since I defined a radius. Here is the costmap_common_params.yaml file :

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
robot_radius: 0.285
inflation_radius: 0.3
max_obstacle_height: 1
min_obstacle_height: 0.0
observation_sources: scan
scan: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

So I don't have any footprint but it's normal. THe same exact file work flawlessly on Groovy, the problem is on hydro.

It follow exactly the same scheme as [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11338/turtlebot-gmapping-and-amcl-demos-fatal-footprint-error-for-move_base/) without being fatal but I though it has been corrected.

Here I ask the robot to go more or less forward...

[image: the crazy robot]

I really don't know what is wrong there. Any help will be greatly appreciated ! Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173705/move_base-footprint/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-06-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK nevermind. Something was fishy in the costmap parameters files and I still don't know what. But I use something rather drastic and I re-wrote all of them as simpler versions (less parameters, closer to the explanation on the move_base page) and now it's working fine. I have no idea what happen but I probably defined something weird somewhere.

Sorry for all the fuzz about it.

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0